# How to ReSize All Controls Of Application With Different Resolutions

Tags: java, swing, layout, deployment, screen-resolution

I am using Swing Application. I have build Many forms in the Resolution (1280*1024). When i am deploying the application in the resolution the forms are clipping in the resolution (1024*768) and other smaller resolutions. I have tried the [MIGLayOutManager](http://www.miglayout.com/)! and [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html)! as these are preferable if you are developing the application from scratch but they do not work for me. I want to resize my child controls of the frame using the 
[Example](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=25685.0)!

Below is the code which i used for **GridBagLayOut** on the edit of Answer by @Guillaume Polet

```
        try {
    Utility util = new Utility(null);
    Component[] com = null;
    java.util.List<Component> jComp = new ArrayList<Component>();
    if (obj instanceof JPanel) {
        JPanel panel = (JPanel) obj;
        com = panel.getComponents();
    } else if (obj instanceof JFrame) {
        JFrame JFrm = (JFrame) obj;

        jComp = util.harvestAllComp(JFrm);

    } else if (obj instanceof JFrame) {

        JFrame frm = (JFrame) obj;
        //  frm.cp = cp;
        String dbName = "GoldNew";
        util = new Utility(dbName);
        DBEngine db = new DBEngine(dbName);

        for (int a = 0; a < jComp.size(); a++) {
            if (jComp.get(a) instanceof JLabel) {

                JLabel label = (JLabel) com[a];
            } else if (jComp.get(a) instanceof JTextField) {
                JTextField jtxt = (JTextField) jComp.get(a);
                jtxt.setEditable(boolEnable);

                // Do Nothing 
            } else if (jComp.get(a) instanceof JTextArea) {
                JTextArea jtxt = (JTextArea) jComp.get(a);
                jtxt.setEditable(boolEnable);

            } else if (jComp.get(a) instanceof JXDatePicker) {
                JXDatePicker jdate = (JXDatePicker) jComp.get(a);
                jdate.setEditable(boolEnable);
                jdate.getEditor().setEditable(false);

                // Do Nothing 
            } else if (jComp.get(a) instanceof JTabbedPane) {
                JTabbedPane tabPane = (JTabbedPane) jComp.get(a);
                Component[] comTab = tabPane.getComponents();
                tabPane.removeAll();
                GridBagLayout tabLayOut = new GridBagLayout();
                tabPane.setLayout(tabLayOut);
                addRowOfComponents(tabPane, comTab);

            } 
            if (jComp.get(a) instanceof JPanel) {
                JPanel panel2 = (JPanel) jComp.get(a);
                Component[] comTab = panel2.getComponents();
                panel2.removeAll();
                GridBagLayout tabLayOut = new GridBagLayout();
                panel2.setLayout(tabLayOut);
                addRowOfComponents(panel2, comTab);

            } else if (jComp.get(a) instanceof JTable) {

                final JTable tbl = (JTable) jComp.get(a);
                tbl.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
            } else if ((!(jComp.get(a) instanceof JTextField)) && (!(jComp.get(a) instanceof JXDatePicker))
                    && (!(jComp.get(a) instanceof JTextArea))
                    && (!(jComp.get(a) instanceof JLabel))) {
                // jComp.get(a).setEnabled(boolEnable);
                jComp.get(a).setEnabled(boolEnable);

            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to use Component Size and Screen Size To Determine Aspect Ratio And Scale Component using Aspect Ration as in [Example](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=25685.0)!    using information below. I will be really thankful if any body guide how to achieve the task.

```
       Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frm.setBounds(0, 0, dim.width - 100, dim.height - 100);
        int w = frm.getSize().width;//Size Of Form
        int h = frm.getSize().height;
        int x = (dim.width - w) / 2;
        int y = (dim.height - h) / 2;
```

Comment: Personally, if you are setting up restrictions for screen sizes, I would possibly add a scroll pane to the top level container so it handle those cases that are below your expectation.  If you're really bent on "resizing" the graphics, I would check out [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) (Java 7) or [JXLayer](http://java.net/projects/jxlayer/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you give some hint for how to use the JXLayer or JLayer in my case.

Comment: @MadProgrammer i have tested adding scrollPane to the jframe , it raises error on compileTime. When i added ScrollPane to the Top level container i.e. JTabPane and JPanel it is not fullfilling the requirement and the form is being clipped in the bottom.

Comment: *"Can you give some hint for how to use the JXLayer or JLayer"* I wish I could, there use to be some excellent examples on the net, but they've vanished. I might have some examples at work

Comment: What errors where you getting with the scroll pane?

Comment: This code i added JScrollPane scrollPaneFrm =new JScrollPane();
                    scrollPaneFrm.setViewportView(frm);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19868/discussion-between-prog-anila-and-madprogrammer)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are incorrectly using LayoutManagers. Instead of setting them on the container, you set them on its content (although this is allowed, this is not done very often).

1. Use a LayoutManager on a `Container`
2. Optionally set constraints on its children component.

Here is a completely dumb example of using `GridBagLayout` which increases or decreases the size of all components according to the size of the frame:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestGridBagLayout {

    protected void initUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle(TestGridBagLayout.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][] { new Object[] { "Cell 1" }, new Object[] { "Cell 2" }, new Object[] { "Cell 3" } },
                new Object[] { "Header 1" });
        JList list = new JList(new Object[] { "Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3", "Element 4" });
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(8, 30);
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", new JLabel("Tab 1"));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", new JLabel("Tab 2"));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 3", new JLabel("Tab 3"));
        addRowOfComponents(mainPanel, new JLabel("A label"), new JButton("A button"), new JTextField("A textfield", 24), new JComboBox(
                new Object[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" }));
        addRowOfComponents(mainPanel, new JScrollPane(table), new JScrollPane(list), new JScrollPane(textArea), tabbedPane);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addRowOfComponents(Container parent, JComponent... children) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            JComponent jComponent = children[i];
            if (i + 1 == children.length) {
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            }
            parent.add(jComponent, gbc);
        }
        parent.revalidate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new TestGridBagLayout().initUI();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: i applied your code to my example and used newRowOf Components for each of my container inside the form but it's working and the form is still clipping from the bottom. on resolution  (1024*768) ;

Comment: Guillaume Polet I have edited my question by applying your answer but it doesnot work for me.

Comment: @Prog_Anila Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) because it is impossible to help you more with the current code we are seeing.

Comment: @downvoter Would you care to explain? Or is it just pure random downvote?

Comment: i have send u the code of my resize Function ( A general Function which i am using for all of my frames) and it is supposed to be a SSCCE. @Guillaume Polet